# Cannot resolve org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am following a tutorial to learn eureka server/client with spring boot. When running the project, I'm encountering the following error.

I'm using,
Java 17
Spring boot v3.1.2
Eureka v4.0.2

**This is pom.xml. I have removed some dependencies**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.javabrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>discovery-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>discovery-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.3.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>4.0.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>4.0.2</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.1.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Below I have added full console output to understand the error.

```
2023-08-24T23:54:37.010+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] i.j.d.DiscoveryServerApplication         : Starting DiscoveryServerApplication using Java 17.0.8 with PID 3260 (D:\microservice\discovery-server\target\classes started by HP in D:\microservice\discovery-server)
2023-08-24T23:54:37.015+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] i.j.d.DiscoveryServerApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-08-24T23:54:38.135+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=89404519-db3b-3b8f-bd02-2deb9b13f336
2023-08-24T23:54:39.084+05:30  WARN 3260 --- [           main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. While this cache implementation is useful for development and tests, it's recommended to use Caffeine cache in production.You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
2023-08-24T23:54:39.323+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2023-08-24T23:54:39.365+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2023-08-24T23:54:39.367+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2023-08-24T23:54:39.375+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1692901479374 with initial instances count: 0
2023-08-24T23:54:39.420+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initializing ...
2023-08-24T23:54:39.421+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http://localhost:8761/eureka/]
2023-08-24T23:54:39.628+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2023-08-24T23:54:39.628+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2023-08-24T23:54:39.628+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2023-08-24T23:54:39.628+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2023-08-24T23:54:39.736+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Replica node URL:  http://localhost:8761/eureka/
2023-08-24T23:54:39.744+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Finished initializing remote region registries. All known remote regions: []
2023-08-24T23:54:39.745+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initialized
2023-08-24T23:54:39.899+05:30  WARN 3260 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaVersionFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eurekaVersionFilterRegistration' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2023-08-24T23:54:39.900+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Shutting down ...
2023-08-24T23:54:39.913+05:30 ERROR 3260 --- [t-Conn-Cleaner2] c.n.d.s.t.j.EurekaJersey3ClientImpl      : Cannot clean connections

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client instance has been closed.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.guava.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:169) ~[jersey-common-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.checkNotClosed(JerseyClient.java:257) ~[jersey-client-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.getConfiguration(JerseyClient.java:372) ~[jersey-client-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.getConfiguration(JerseyClient.java:56) ~[jersey-client-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey3.EurekaJersey3ClientImpl$ConnectionCleanerTask.run(EurekaJersey3ClientImpl.java:347) ~[eureka-client-jersey3-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-08-24T23:54:39.923+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Shut down
2023-08-24T23:54:39.930+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2023-08-24T23:54:39.931+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
2023-08-24T23:54:39.948+05:30  INFO 3260 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-08-24T23:54:39.971+05:30 ERROR 3260 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method eurekaVersionFilterRegistration in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' in your configuration.
```

This is my Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

How can I solve this problem and why is it happening?

Comment: I suspect you aren't following the tutorial and decided to use the newest version of Spring Boot. This error comes generally from using incompatible versions. If you are following a tutorial then follow the tutorial (including the version ranges in use).

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, I used the latest versions. The tutorial follows Java 11. I try to study the latest.

Comment: So you aren't following the tutorial, but doing something akin to the tutorial. Follow the tutorial **including the versions used**. If that works read the documentation onhow to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Your exact code ran ok (started successfully) on my machine (except for jar packaging and i ran it with embedded tomcat).

Used Java 17,maven 3.8.1, Spring boot v3.1.2 Eureka v4.0.2.

There should be no problem with your versions because they are compatible in official Spring's compatibility matrix.
Perhaps you deploy the war to an incompatible app server (eg Tomcat?)

Comment: I'm using openlogic-openjdk-17.0.8. I try to just run on my machine. I'll try again. Tnks.